# Long Range Omnidirectional Wifi in Urban without line of sight

Tags: wireless-networking, range

I want to share my wifi connection to my friends which are in all direction around me but less than 11km away.

How can I achieve an omnidirectional wifi signal of about 11km. because there are many trees and buildings between us and they want to connect their iPads and laptop?

Comment: That’s simply impossible. It might be possible with dedicated backhaul links and local WiFi cells, but it’s just too expensive.

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply. Nothing is impossible, how much?

Comment: Only 11 km? With buildings and trees (a forest?) in the way? You are talking about WiFi (B/G/N), with an average range of 100 or 200 feet, right?

Answer (score 1):

Nanostation 5, Rocket M5 for omni-d. Compelte kit here:
http://www.balticnetworks.com/ubiquiti-airmax-5ghz-ptmp-omni-directional-mid-range-link-starter-kit.html

Practically, if you have just a few friends, its better to setup some nanostation 5s in point to point mode. At 11km, city conditions considered, it will be good from a signal/speed perspective.

Comment: Is that a WiFI 802.11x device? It does not appear to be. According to the FCC, the WiFi limit of total output is 1 watt, and this device outputs 40 watts. And it costs $625.00 (US?)

Comment: Its also not even released yet.

Comment: I use NS5s and Rocket at 4 to 12 KM currently with no problem. Output is matter of regulation, not capabilities. The stations have an option to comply or not with power emission standards (it even is country-based). Cost is not the subject here.

Comment: How many users do you have on your network? and what about your line of sight status? do they receive equal speed or signal at 12km? @Overmind

Comment: There are sets 5 of 2 to 12 users connected. Signal is above 40% at all times, depending more on magnetic interference rather than distance. No speed problems were reported, but most of the users are not high bandwidth users (no continuous p2p traffic). After each NS5 there is a 4/8/16 port depending on the number of users.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The only way to increase the range of a radio signal at those distances would be to increase your transmit power. That would require specialized equipment and most likely a license from the government (at least that's how it would work in the US).

The only other option would be a parabolic dish, but that's (obviously) not omnidirectional and you need line-of-sight for that.